# Can a member function be const like in C++?

Tags: dart

Say I have a C++ function signature:

```cpp
bool Foo::bar() const;
```

where the "const" at the end indicates that no member variables in Foo will change by calling bar. Is there a Dart equivalent of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, I don't think so. If you think it will be great to have such a feature, please star [issue 7908](http://dartbug.com/7908).

Comment: Filed: http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=7908&thanks=7908&ts=1358245478